# Transforming a dataset containing bank transactions into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to transform a dataset containing some bank transactions.
The ultimate goal is to make a report in Power BI to track daily expenses.

For this, I have the following situation that gives me a headache. :)

This is an example:

| Date | Transaction_Details | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 Jan 2023 | Transfer HomeBank | 500 | NULL |
| NULL | Reference: 4944 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | Beneficiary: David John | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | In Bank Account: RO97INGB1111333380218 | 500 | NULL |
| 20 Jan 2023 | POS Payment | 36 | NULL |
| NULL | Card number: xxxx xxxx xxxx 1020 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | Terminal: OZKARDES A/S | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | Date: 19-01-2023 | NULL | NULL |

The desired output would be to transpose all rows in Transaction_Details that have NULL values in Date column, into a new column (e.g Other_Details) and for each transaction to add another column with "Transaction_Key".
Below, I have attached an example:

| Transaction_Key | Date | Transaction_Details | Other_Details | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 Jan 2023 | Transfer HomeBank | Reference: 4944, Beneficiary: David John, In Bank Account: RO97INGB1111333380218 | 500 | NULL |
| 2 | 20 Jan 2023 | POS Payment | Card number: xxxx xxxx xxxx 1020, Terminal: OZKARDES A/S, Date: 19-01-2023 | 36 | NULL |

I used some COALESCE functions but it didn't work.

Comment: tables are by nature unsorted, so a query can't determine which row belongs to which transaction

Comment: Is there another column which has a proper sequence ?  Datetime, Identity, ... ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Unfortunately, no. Apparently, the developers didn't think anyone would want to do some SQL stuff on this data :)

Comment: @nbk, this is sad..

Comment: You need to provide some additional information, it requires a column that either provides a natural sequence or links/groups the rows that belong to each transaction.

Comment: 1)Please add a column to group records for every transaction 2) Execute UPDATE Ta SET Date = () WHERE Date IS NULL

Comment: @Stu, I think both would help me. But unfortunately, I don't know how to implement either option.

Comment: It's not "sad", @SergiuSAsas96 , it's by design. Tables aren't Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: @Larnu , Yes, actually.. the source is an Excel spreadsheet. Probably the files are made in such a way that they can only be used for Excel.

Comment: @SergiuSAsas96 It's not something you would implement, unless you are going manually  create a column and update it; you either have the data or you do not, without it there is nothing to associate with any particular row; If the source is an import from Excel then add a row number in Excel and import that with the data.

Comment: @Larnu Do you think using the hidden field containing the physical location (`%%physloc%%`) can help retrieve the ordering of the data?

Comment: @Stu, This means manually adding and creating a new column in Excel. It would be simple but the table contains 3000 rows.
It would be too much work. That's why I thought of a BI solution, because I would just run some stored procedures and refresh the report in Power BI and my expenses would update.

Comment: @SergiuSAsas96, do you mean the transaction data set originates in Excel? Records in a file are ordered so you can assign an incremental value during the import.

Comment: You can create a number sequence in Excel easily, #rows is irrelevant, takes seconds.

Comment: @Stu, How does adding an Identity column help me?

Comment: @SergiuSAsas96 it's enough to group the rows together, I have proposed an answer below you can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume you are able to create an Id/Sequence either in the data source or when importing the data, such that you end up with an incrementing number per row, then by using a windowed aggregation as follows you can convert your data as required:

```
select Transaction_Key, 
    Max(Date) Date, 
    Max(case when date is not null then Transaction_Details end) Transaction_Details,
    String_Agg(case when date is null then Transaction_Details end, ',') Other_details,
    Max(case when date is not null then Debit end) Debit,
    Max(case when date is not null then Credit end) Credit
from (
    select *, 
      Sum(case when date is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by id) as Transaction_Key
    from t
)t
group by Transaction_Key;
```

See this [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JlF1VaWW)

Comment: Your SQL script is a gold mine for me. Many thanks!!!!!